# NullReferenceException when adding buttons to Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to add number of buttons in container of a Panel in window Form, my implementation is as follows:

```
protected override void Order_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
  Menu = new MenuForm();
  CatButtons = new Button[5];
  CatButtons[0] = new Button();
  CatButtons[0].Text = "ljjih";
  CatButtons[0].Click += new System.EventHandler(btn_Click);
  Menu.Cat_Panel.Container.Add(CatButtons[0]);
}
```

I keep getting System.NullReferenceException at the last line

```
Menu.Cat_Panel.Container.Add(CatButtons[0]);
```

Note : CatButtons and Menu are already declared globally

Comment: Seems that `Menu.Cat_Panel` (or its `Container`) is null.

Comment: Who takes care to initialize the Cat_Panel inside the MenuForm()?

Comment: Initialized in MenuForms by :

Comment: `this.Cat_Panel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();`

Comment: But the button should be added to the Controls collection not to the Container. Right?

Comment: `Note : CatButtons and Menu are already declared globally` declaring a variable is not the same as creating an instance

Comment: @Steve you are right i missed that, it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Replaced :

```
Menu.Cat_Panel.Container.Add(CatButtons[0]);
```

with:

```
Menu.Cat_Panel.Controls.Add(CatButtons[0]);
```

And it Worked

Answer (score 0):

I might be stating the obvious but does Cat_Panel exists as its not in the code snippet you show ?  If it doesnt it would explain the Null Reference exception.

Worth checking the existance of that first.